# Why can't we allow tags related to criticism?

Tags: discussion, tags

Anyone who knows and follows Hinduism knows well about the criticism of Hinduism by experts from other domains.

In India, most Hindus are aware of books written by great people like Ambedkar that criticize Hinduism. They include `Annihilation-of-caste`, `Riddles-in-Hinduism` etc., These books are very popular and intended for a wide audience.

Several elite followers or preachers of Sanathan dharma might already counter all the arguments made in those books.

In fact, many questions on our main site either directly or indirectly cite the arguments from those books only. Since our site deals with Hinduism and anyone can seek answers for any arguments, that may be against Sanathan dharma, I feel that we can allow **tags that contain names of those books** that argues against Hinduism so that expert users from our site can counter and post the answer from scriptures.

Is there any wrong in doing so?

---

Note that I am asking this question for names of books as tags **that can be allowed in question only** and it is **no way related to the answers**. Answers should be from the scriptures of Hinduism and as per the guidelines currently followed by our community.